# How to use fold to keep the values between function calls

Tags: haskell

Consider having a list of 3 numbers where each number specify a shift in position and their value changes like this:

x starts off as zero and increases by one until 9 then y does the same and then z does the same. When they are all 9 they reset to zero.

I have written the following to that:

```
ShiftInX :: ShiftBy->ShiftBy
ShiftInX [z,y,9] = ShiftInY [z,y,0]
ShiftInX [z,y,x] = [z,y,x+1]

ShiftInY :: ShiftBy->ShiftBy
ShiftInY [z,9,0] = ShiftInZ [z,0,0]
ShiftInY [z,y,0] = [z,y+1,0]

ShiftInZ :: ShiftBy->ShiftBy
ShiftInZ [9,0,0] = [0,0,0]
ShiftInZ [z,0,0] = [z+1,0,0]
```

Also, there are 3 strings:

```
s1 = "ahsgtdfyu"
s2 = "kfhyrdncl"
s3 = "polsedrtd"
```

Given a string, I want to take each character of the given string, find it in s3, shift it by x, take that letter and find it in s2, shift it by y, take that letter and find it in s3 and shift it by z and retuen the character.
Do the same for each character of the given string. Before processing each character, the ShiftBy list changes as described at the begining.

I have written a function that gets a character and a shiftBy list as input and returns a character as output. It finds the output caharacter as described above.
    findChar :: String -> Char -> [Int] -> Char

Problem: I want to be able to call this function for each character of the given string but not loose the values of the shiftBy numbers so that the shiftBy number increase for each new character.
processString :: String -> [Int] -> String

I used map for this but the values are lost after each characetr is processed.

I am told i have to use Fold or explicit recursion for this. I understand what fold does but don't know how to use it here. Can anyone please help with this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is very confusing. If I understand correctly, you have a sort of encryption scheme, where s1, s2 and s3 are the key and the ShiftBy list is an encryption state that changes as you go through the string to be encrypted.

What I don't understand is what you mean by  "find it in s3, shift it by x". Do you mean a ROT encoding? Do you mean finding the index and then adding x to it to find the next character, rotating around the end? Do you mean actually modifying the key?

In any case, it sounds like the signature of your current character encryption function is

```
encryptChar :: Char -> ShiftBy -> Char
```

when it should be

```
encryptChar :: Char -> ShiftBy -> (Char, ShiftBy)
```

i.e. it needs to return the adjusted encryption state.

Or alternatively, don't pass out the altered encryption state and modify it outside, since it doesn't depend on the character.

So as for the fold, the key is to make the encryption state part of the fold state. Here's one way to do this:

```
-- Given:
encryptChar :: Char -> ShiftBy -> Char
adjustShiftState :: ShiftBy -> ShiftBy -- really just an alias of ShiftInX
-- You can fold thus:
encrypt :: String -> String
encrypt msg = fst $ foldr foldOne initialState msg
    where initialState = ("", [0, 0, 0])
          foldOne ch (encryptedString, shiftState) =
            (encryptChar ch shiftState : encryptedString, adjustShiftState shiftState)
```

In other words, as you fold, you always keep a pair of the encrypted string so far and the current shift state. At the very end of the encryption, you take the result string and throw the shift state away.

The above is efficient; however, it doesn't do quite what you want, since it goes through the string in reverse. You need a left fold, which (because the way `:` works) is a bit more complicated, and probably less efficient. (Judicious application of strict left fold and strictness markers could probably be used after profiling reveals issues.)

Here's the left fold version:

```
encrypt msg = fst $ foldl foldOne msg initialState
    where initialState = ("", [0, 0, 0])
          foldOne (encryptedString, shiftState) ch =
            (encryptedString ++ [encryptChar ch shiftState],
             adjustShiftState shiftState)
```

Note the use of list concatenation instead of simple cons.